# Implement React-pagination with Rest Api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, spring-boot, material-ui

I have this Spring Boot endpoint for listing items from database:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/task", produces = 
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> processTask(@Valid TaskSearchParams params, Pageable pageable)
{
    Page<TaskDto> taskList = service.findTasks(params, pageable);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(taskList, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Search DTO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class TaskSearchParams {

    private Integer id;

    private String title;
}
```

Material Table:

```
import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { createStyles, lighten, makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TablePagination from '@material-ui/core/TablePagination';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import TableSortLabel from '@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import FilterListIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FilterList';

interface Data {
    calories: number;
    carbs: number;
    fat: number;
    name: string;
    protein: number;
}

function createData(
    name: string,
    calories: number,
    fat: number,
    carbs: number,
    protein: number,
): Data {
    return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
    createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
    createData('Donut', 452, 25.0, 51, 4.9),
    createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
    createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
    createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
    createData('Honeycomb', 408, 3.2, 87, 6.5),
    createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
    createData('Jelly Bean', 375, 0.0, 94, 0.0),
    createData('KitKat', 518, 26.0, 65, 7.0),
    createData('Lollipop', 392, 0.2, 98, 0.0),
    createData('Marshmallow', 318, 0, 81, 2.0),
    createData('Nougat', 360, 19.0, 9, 37.0),
    createData('Oreo', 437, 18.0, 63, 4.0),
];

function descendingComparator<T>(a: T, b: T, orderBy: keyof T) {
    if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

type Order = 'asc' | 'desc';

function getComparator<Key extends keyof any>(
    order: Order,
    orderBy: Key,
): (a: { [key in Key]: number | string }, b: { [key in Key]: number | string }) => number {
    return order === 'desc'
        ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
        : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
}

function stableSort<T>(array: T[], comparator: (a: T, b: T) => number) {
    const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index] as [T, number]);
    stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
        const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
        if (order !== 0) return order;
        return a[1] - b[1];
    });
    return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
}

interface HeadCell {
    disablePadding: boolean;
    id: keyof Data;
    label: string;
    numeric: boolean;
}

const headCells: HeadCell[] = [
    { id: 'name', numeric: false, disablePadding: true, label: 'Dessert (100g serving)' },
    { id: 'calories', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Calories' },
    { id: 'fat', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Fat (g)' },
    { id: 'carbs', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Carbs (g)' },
    { id: 'protein', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Protein (g)' },
];

interface EnhancedTableProps {
    classes: ReturnType<typeof useStyles>;
    numSelected: number;
    onRequestSort: (event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>, property: keyof Data) => void;
    onSelectAllClick: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
    order: Order;
    orderBy: string;
    rowCount: number;
}

function EnhancedTableHead(props: EnhancedTableProps) {
    const { classes, onSelectAllClick, order, orderBy, numSelected, rowCount, onRequestSort } = props;
    const createSortHandler = (property: keyof Data) => (event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>) => {
        onRequestSort(event, property);
    };

    return (
        <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                    <Checkbox
                        indeterminate={numSelected > 0 && numSelected < rowCount}
                        checked={rowCount > 0 && numSelected === rowCount}
                        onChange={onSelectAllClick}
                        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'select all desserts' }}
                    />
                </TableCell>
                {headCells.map((headCell) => (
                    <TableCell
                        key={headCell.id}
                        align={headCell.numeric ? 'right' : 'left'}
                        padding={headCell.disablePadding ? 'none' : 'normal'}
                        sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
                    >
                        <TableSortLabel
                            active={orderBy === headCell.id}
                            direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : 'asc'}
                            onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
                        >
                            {headCell.label}
                            {orderBy === headCell.id ? (
                                <span className={classes.visuallyHidden}>
                  {order === 'desc' ? 'sorted descending' : 'sorted ascending'}
                </span>
                            ) : null}
                        </TableSortLabel>
                    </TableCell>
                ))}
            </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
    );
}

const useToolbarStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        root: {
            paddingLeft: theme.spacing(2),
            paddingRight: theme.spacing(1),
        },
        highlight:
            theme.palette.type === 'light'
                ? {
                    color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
                    backgroundColor: lighten(theme.palette.secondary.light, 0.85),
                }
                : {
                    color: theme.palette.text.primary,
                    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.dark,
                },
        title: {
            flex: '1 1 100%',
        },
    }),
);

interface EnhancedTableToolbarProps {
    numSelected: number;
}

const EnhancedTableToolbar = (props: EnhancedTableToolbarProps) => {
    const classes = useToolbarStyles();
    const { numSelected } = props;

    return (
        <Toolbar
            className={clsx(classes.root, {
                [classes.highlight]: numSelected > 0,
            })}
        >
            {numSelected > 0 ? (
                <Typography className={classes.title} color="inherit" variant="subtitle1" component="div">
                    {numSelected} selected
                </Typography>
            ) : (
                <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h6" id="tableTitle" component="div">
                    Nutrition
                </Typography>
            )}
            {numSelected > 0 ? (
                <Tooltip title="Delete">
                    <IconButton aria-label="delete">
                        <DeleteIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
            ) : (
                <Tooltip title="Filter list">
                    <IconButton aria-label="filter list">
                        <FilterListIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
            )}
        </Toolbar>
    );
};

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        root: {
            width: '100%',
        },
        paper: {
            width: '100%',
            marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
        },
        table: {
            minWidth: 750,
        },
        visuallyHidden: {
            border: 0,
            clip: 'rect(0 0 0 0)',
            height: 1,
            margin: -1,
            overflow: 'hidden',
            padding: 0,
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 20,
            width: 1,
        },
    }),
);

export default function AllBusinessCustomers() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [order, setOrder] = React.useState<Order>('asc');
    const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = React.useState<keyof Data>('calories');
    const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
    const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
    const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(5);

    const handleRequestSort = (event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>, property: keyof Data) => {
        const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === 'asc';
        setOrder(isAsc ? 'desc' : 'asc');
        setOrderBy(property);
    };

    const handleSelectAllClick = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (event.target.checked) {
            const newSelecteds = rows.map((n) => n.name);
            setSelected(newSelecteds);
            return;
        }
        setSelected([]);
    };

    const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>, name: string) => {
        const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(name);
        let newSelected: string[] = [];

        if (selectedIndex === -1) {
            newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, name);
        } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
            newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
        } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
            newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
        } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
            newSelected = newSelected.concat(
                selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
                selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1),
            );
        }

        setSelected(newSelected);
    };

    const handleChangePage = (event: unknown, newPage: number) => {
        setPage(newPage);
    };

    const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
        setPage(0);
    };

    const isSelected = (name: string) => selected.indexOf(name) !== -1;

    const emptyRows = rowsPerPage - Math.min(rowsPerPage, rows.length - page * rowsPerPage);

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                <EnhancedTableToolbar numSelected={selected.length} />
                <TableContainer>
                    <Table
                        className={classes.table}
                        aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
                        size={'medium'}
                        aria-label="enhanced table"
                    >
                        <EnhancedTableHead
                            classes={classes}
                            numSelected={selected.length}
                            order={order}
                            orderBy={orderBy}
                            onSelectAllClick={handleSelectAllClick}
                            onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
                            rowCount={rows.length}
                        />
                        <TableBody>
                            {stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
                                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                                .map((row, index) => {
                                    const isItemSelected = isSelected(row.name);
                                    const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;

                                    return (
                                        <TableRow
                                            hover
                                            onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row.name)}
                                            role="checkbox"
                                            aria-checked={isItemSelected}
                                            tabIndex={-1}
                                            key={row.name}
                                            selected={isItemSelected}
                                        >
                                            <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                                                <Checkbox
                                                    checked={isItemSelected}
                                                    inputProps={{ 'aria-labelledby': labelId }}
                                                />
                                            </TableCell>
                                            <TableCell component="th" id={labelId} scope="row" padding="none">
                                                {row.name}
                                            </TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
                                        </TableRow>
                                    );
                                })}
                            {emptyRows > 0 && (
                                <TableRow style={{ height: 53 * emptyRows }}>
                                    <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                                </TableRow>
                            )}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </TableContainer>
                <TablePagination
                    rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
                    component="div"
                    count={rows.length}
                    rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                    page={page}
                    onPageChange={handleChangePage}
                    onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
                />
            </Paper>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Ref: https://material-ui.com/components/tables/

What is the proper way to build `Paged` object using `React-Pagination` with Typescript and send appropriate payload using this table?

Comment: It would be much faster to answer if you create a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example with a question exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: Do you want to fetch all data with one API call and sort filter data in UI? I think you need to fetch from frontend with sort and filter options and BE filter/sort data.

Comment: @FiodorovAndrei I want to send appropriate `Paged` object generated into UI and use lazy loading to get get the data for the current table page. I will receive from Spring Boot this example data: https://www.bezkoder.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/spring-boot-pagination-filter-example-spring-jpa-pageable-default.png The issue is how to implement the Typescript logic?

Comment: @Nishant https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-tiymkf?file=Hello.tsx

Comment: That Stackblitz version is not working, maybe try codesandbox? https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-leaf-d0zy2?file=/src/Hello.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably get started with something like:

```
  const [rows, setRows] = React.useState<Data[]>([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `http://localhost:8080/api/tutorials?page=${page}&limit=${rowsPerPage}`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setRows(data.tutorials));
  }, [page, rowsPerPage]);
```

This way when `page` or `rowsPerPage`, new data is fetched. Then maybe add some loading indicator etc.

That would load the single page only, and only when it's requested. Now if you would want to cache these so jumping back and forth wouldn't generate new requests always, you could look into `SWR` or `react-query`. Those libraries also allow some prefetching, so if you want some fancy stuff like prefetching the next page on the background, those can do that.

Also keep in mind that it's ok to do paging and sorting and stuff in the client side, if the row count is not that big, just like you are doing already. When you should start paging in the server side depends on the target audience (or target devices) and on how heavy the data is.

For more on client side vs server side, check this blog for example: https://buildthis.com/client-side-vs-server-side-pagination/

Edit: Added a bit more code to make the usage clearer

Comment: Thank you. Can you show me how this code can be used into the table code , please?

Comment: I added some more code around the example now. So in your example you would remove the const rows you are now using in the Hello.tsx, and add this inside the Hello() function below the multiple React.useState calls.

Comment: See https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-payne-3wwg4?file=/src/Hello.tsx

Comment: Thank you. I created a test BE and I tried this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-scott-31frc?file=/src/Hello.tsx

Comment: This is the test data: http://185.185.126.15:8080/api/merchants/onboarding/task

Comment: The codesandbox doesn't give much to go on, running locally would probably give better errors, but I would say it might be a CORS issue: https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9

Comment: anyway. By looking at the code can you advise some improvements, please? for sure you can try to run it locally. I can run it.

Comment: If you run both frontend and backend on the same localhost, using localhost as address, then the CORS shouldn't be an issue. That's an easy way to confirm that it's the cause. If so, then there are tutorials on how to configure the backend to allow that if they are in different domains, like https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: Also running locally it works fine for me with that backend URL you provided.

Comment: can you propose some improvements of the code?

Comment: Well in the `setOrderBy(property);`, you could use the previous value so you don't change it unnecessarily, like `setOrderBy(prevOrderBy => prevOrderBy === property ? prevOrderBy : property);`. Other than that it looked ok on a quick overview.

Comment: Do you know how I can implement delete functionality for this table?

Comment: That's out of the scope of this question in my opinion. If you need help with that, open a new question.